# Linq Groupby Elapsed Time

Tags: c#, linq, time, linq-group

I need to group by a list by owner, town and "timeout".
I will explain "timeout":

```
public class Ticket
{
    public int pk { get; set; }
    public string owner { get; set; }
    public string reffering { get; set; }
    public DateTime? created_time { get; set; }
}
```

And I got a List.
I want to create a List> where each sublist contains a list of tickets where created_time is less than 10 seconds.

Here is a sample list of tickets :

```
pk   owner   reffering   created_time
#1   John    Sam         15/11/2017 11:33:20
#2   John    Sam         15/11/2017 11:33:21
#3   Pat     Jerry       15/11/2017 11:33:27
#4   John    Sam         15/11/2017 11:33:28
#6   Pat     Jerry       15/11/2017 11:33:35
#5   John    Sam         15/11/2017 11:34:00
```

And I need to get a list of list with

```
   pk   owner   reffering   created_time
---#1 Sub List ---
    #1   John    Sam         15/11/2017 11:33:20
    #2   John    Sam         15/11/2017 11:33:21
    #4   John    Sam         15/11/2017 11:33:28
---#2 Sub List ---
    #5   John    Sam         15/11/2017 11:34:00
---#3 Sub List ---
    #3   Pat     Jerry       15/11/2017 11:33:27
    #6   Pat     Jerry       15/11/2017 11:33:35
```

Here my starting code but I can find out how to do this..

```
List<List<Ticket>> result = tickets.OrderBy(p => p.created_time).GroupBy(p => new { p.owner, p.reffering }).Select(g => g.ToList()).ToList();
```

Hope some can help especially with the elapsed time.. it makes me crazy!

Comment: time diff between `#3 Pat Jerry` and `#6 Pat Jerry` is 8 s but you have separated it. Is it correct?

Comment: What do you mean 10 seconds? Is that 10s chunks or all elements are within 10s of each other?

Comment: @sarslan yes because the timeout it's out! > 10 seconds and we have to get it in a different sub list

Comment: @FilipCordas I want to group elements by owner and town and then group elements where ticket created time is less that 10 seconds previous ticket.

Comment: @karim which is the base time. First row or previous row?

Comment: @karimharfakti your expected result is not made sense. #3 and #6 should be in the same group.

Comment: @sarslan the previous row

Comment: @EdwardN you are right sorry i change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure you can do all of this with LINQ, here is my implementation as your references

```
var ticketGroups = tickets.OrderBy(x => x.created_time)
                            .GroupBy(x => new { x.owner, x.reffering });
var tensecondTimespam = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10);
var results = new List<List<Ticket>>();
var ticketTemps = new List<Ticket>();

foreach (var ticketGroup in ticketGroups)
{
    foreach (var ticket in ticketGroup)
    {
        var currentTicket = ticketTemps.LastOrDefault();
        var isWithinTimeRange = currentTicket == null
                                || ticket.created_time.Value - currentTicket.created_time.Value <= tensecondTimespam;

        if (!isWithinTimeRange)
        {
            results.Add(ticketTemps);
            ticketTemps = new List<Ticket>();
        }
        ticketTemps.Add(ticket);
    }
    if (ticketTemps.Any())
    {
        results.Add(ticketTemps);
        ticketTemps = new List<Ticket>();
    }
}
```

**The result variable will hold your expected output**

Answer (score 1):

Here is something that could help. 
It is grouping the entries by fixed buckets of 10 seconds.

```
void Main()
{
    var ticketsList = new List<Ticket>();
    ticketsList.Add(new Ticket { pk = 1, owner="John", reffering="Sam"  , created_time = new DateTime(2017, 11, 15, 11, 33, 20) });
    ticketsList.Add(new Ticket { pk = 2, owner="John", reffering="Sam"  , created_time = new DateTime(2017, 11, 15, 11, 33, 21) });
    ticketsList.Add(new Ticket { pk = 3, owner="Pat" , reffering="Jerry", created_time = new DateTime(2017, 11, 15, 11, 33, 27) });
    ticketsList.Add(new Ticket { pk = 4, owner="John", reffering="Sam"  , created_time = new DateTime(2017, 11, 15, 11, 33, 28) });
    ticketsList.Add(new Ticket { pk = 6, owner="Pat" , reffering="Jerry", created_time = new DateTime(2017, 11, 15, 11, 33, 35) });
    ticketsList.Add(new Ticket { pk = 5, owner="John", reffering="Sam"  , created_time = new DateTime(2017, 11, 15, 11, 34, 00) });

    var now = DateTime.Now;


    var orderedList = ticketsList.OrderBy(p => p.created_time).GroupBy(p => new { p.owner, p.reffering }).Select(g => g.ToList());

    // Here is the 10 seconds grouping. I'm basically creating a new date 
    // starting at the beginning of a 10 seconds interval. I will then 
    // use this new date to perform the grouping.
    var normalizedGroupKeysList = ticketsList.Select(t => new { ticket = t, groupKey = t.created_time.HasValue ? t.created_time.Value.AddSeconds(-t.created_time.Value.Second % 10) : now });

    var result = normalizedGroupKeysList.GroupBy(t => t.groupKey, t => t.ticket);
}

public class Ticket
{
    public int pk { get; set; }
    public string owner { get; set; }
    public string reffering { get; set; }

    public DateTime? created_time { get; set; }
}
```

The output is:

```
Key=    11/15/2017 11:33:20 AM
pk  owner   reffering   created_time
1   John    Sam 11/15/2017 11:33:20 AM
2   John    Sam 11/15/2017 11:33:21 AM
3   Pat Jerry   11/15/2017 11:33:27 AM
4   John    Sam 11/15/2017 11:33:28 AM      

Key=    11/15/2017 11:33:30 AM
pk  owner   reffering   created_time
6   Pat Jerry   11/15/2017 11:33:35 AM

Key=    11/15/2017 11:34:00 AM
pk  owner   reffering   created_time
5   John    Sam 11/15/2017 11:34:00 AM
```

If you want to dynamically group your tickets dynamically by group of 10 seconds in dynamic buckets, you should need some clustering algorithm to find the best partition of your data.

Comment: your output is not what OP expected it is